# UI Flutter about Column And Row

Tags: flutter, dart

I have design like this

[image: click image]

I tried adding 2 rows in the column and I got an error. that is, it exceeds the screen or the chart may not be rendered

this is my code

```
body: RefreshIndicator(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 320),
                    child: chart,
                  ),
                  onTap: (){
                    _showDialog();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 65),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: (){},
                      child: new Text("LAPOR"),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 36),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      onPressed: (){},
                      child: new Text("PENGUMPULAN"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          onRefresh: _showDialog
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your widgets in a SafeArea class

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html
https://www.youtube.com/embed/lkF0TQJO0bA